# Add new column in dataflow in fabric, as combination of two existing columns

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, fabric

I have a table in my dataflow in fabric, with several columns including one with "LastName" and other with "FirstName".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRMYR.png)

I would like to add another column called "FullName" as a combination of the values in the "FirstName" and "LastName" columns.

How do I do that?

I went to the "Add column" menu and choose "Custom column", but then didn't know how to combine the values of both columns.

Comment: You need to concat the two columns together, with a “ “ as well

Answer (score 0):

You're right to go to the add column tab. The syntax is just a tad different.

[FirstName] & " " & [LastName]

[Screenshot of Custom Column Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K56sD.png)